# Mathematica FindFit error

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to do simple fit to test FindFit and NonlinearModelFit but I get

```
General::ivar: 0.` is not a valid variable
```

error.
My code is quite simple and I just took it from Mathematica example.

```
Table[Prime[x], {x, 20}];
FindFit[%, a x Log[b + c x], {a, b, c}, x]
```

Do you know any reason that this might be happening? I also tried with other data sets and other expression and formats but same error. Also it gives the same error with NonlinearModelFit.

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 4}, {7, 5}};
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, x]
```

I think there is something trivial that I am missing.

Comment: Maybe you will get more answers if you post that question on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restarting the kernel or just evaluate

```
ClearAll[x, a, b, c]
```

Your code works without errors in fresh kernel session.